# Remove everything between <title> and </title> without regex

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

If I have the following string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Coverage report</title>
</head>
</html>
```

and would like to remove

```
<title>Coverage report</title>
```

, I can easily manage by writing a regular express.

BUT as I understand, this is bad practice.

How can I do that with an html parser in Python?

Comment: If you're using `BeautifulSoup` you could do something like `bs.title.text` which is way easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `BeautifulSoup`'s tools is the way:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Coverage report</title>
    </head>
    </html>'''
bs = BeautifulSoup(string, 'lxml')
bs.title.extract()
print(bs)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>

</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you read the `OP` question carefully ? `and would like to remove`

Comment: Pay attention for your code format. and don't forget to include `feature` to not getting a warning from the interpreter . I've made the edit. you can review it.

Comment: What's the point of the `new` variable? `bs` is mutable so you don't need to asign it to a variable that will never be used

Comment: was editing the answer while you typing. just involved the future to ignore the warning.